# "Float" object is not iterable when applying reduce + sum in python2

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, reduce

I want to apply `reduce(sum, iterable)` to a list of float numbers
`flist = [0.2, 0.06, 0.1, 0.05, 0.04, 0.3]`.

`print list(reduce(sum, flist))` returns
`TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Why, when `flist` IS an iterable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual problem is with the `sum` function. It accepts only an iterable, not two individual values. For example,

```
>>> sum(1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>> sum([1, 2])
3
```

So, you cannot use `sum` here, instead you can use a custom lambda function or [`operator.add`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.add), like this

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> reduce(add, flist, 0.0)
0.75
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, flist, 0.0)
0.75
```

**Note:** Before using `reduce`, you might want to read the [BDFL's take on its use](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196). Moreover, `reduce` has been moved to `functools` module in Python 3.x.

Comment: yes, it is `sum` which complains, accordingly `reduce(mul, flist)` does not produce this kind of error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce as follows which will sum up all elements in flist:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,flist)
```

which gives you 0.75.

In this particular case you do not need reduce but could also just use

```
sum(flist)
```